# Duda sobre como crear un selector con Jquery

Tags: jquery, css

Como hago un selector con `jQuery` que me arroje todos los `inputs` cuyo atributo `name` comienzan con la palabra 'pagos' (sin comillas) y **que no tengan** el atributo 'finiquito' (sin comillas)

Ejemplo: En la siguiente lista el selector `jQuery` me debería seleccionar todos los `inputs` menos el tercero ya que ese tiene el atributo `finiquito`

```
<input name="pagos1" type="text" moneda="">
<input name="pagos4" type="text" moneda="">
<input name="pagos5" finiquito type="text" moneda="">
<input name="pagos5" type="text" moneda="">
```

Comment: Bienvenido Ivan, te recomiendo que hagas un  [Recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) y revises el apartado [Cómo Preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que puedas ver las características que debe tener tu pregunta para que sea bien recibida.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yendo por partes:

Para seleccionar un elemento por un atributo habría que poner el elemento y, entre corchetes `[]` el nombre del atributo.

Por ejemplo, para seleccionar un `input` que contenga un elemento `name` sería:

```
input[name]
```

Ahora, para coger un `input` cuyo `name` tenga un valor especifico, solo habría que igualar el `name` al valor correspondiente:

```
input[name=pagos]
```

Pero, como es tu caso, si buscas un elemento cuyo `name` comience por una palabra específica, pero contenga más caracteres:

```
input[name^=pagos]
```

Ya tenemos cómo coger un elemento cuyo `name` comienza por una cadena específica. De igual manera, podemos coger cualquier elemento que tenga el atributo `finiquito` (`[finiquito]`), faltaría negar que tenga este atributo que lo puedes hacer con `:not()`.

```
:not([finiquito])
```

Ahora solo tendrías que juntarlo todo y crear un único selector que cogiera todos los `input` cuyo `name` comience por "pagos", pero que no tengan el atributo `finiquito` (los selectores de JQuery son selectores de CSS):

---

```css
input[name^=pagos]:not([finiquito]) {
  background:red;
}
```

```html
<input name="pagos1" type="text" moneda="">
<input name="pagos4" type="text" moneda="">
<input name="pagos5" finiquito type="text" moneda="">
<input name="pagos5" type="text" moneda="">
```

Comment: Funciono perfectamente y tu explicación fué muy clara, muchas gracias!
El selector jquery quedo así: $('input[name^=pagos]:not([finiquito])')

Answer (score 0):

Utilizandolo como si fuera CSS, entre corchetes y con el `*` para indicar que coincida con cualquier palabra, luego con [`.not()`](http://api.jquery.com/not/) para indicar que no seleccione el atributo deseado.

```js
(function() {
  var selector = $('input[name*=pagos]').not('[finiquito]');
  
  console.log(selector.length);
})()
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input name="otro0" type="text" moneda="">

<input name="pagos1" type="text" moneda="">
<input name="pagos4" type="text" moneda="">
<input name="pagos5" finiquito type="text" moneda="">
<input name="pagos5" type="text" moneda="">

<input name="otro6" type="text" moneda="">
```

---

Te dejo este sitio para ver como funcionan los [selectores CSS](https://code.tutsplus.com/es/tutorials/the-30-css-selectors-you-must-memorize--net-16048).